# Using L'Hospital's Rule for Fourier's series

Tags: calculus, indeterminate-forms

The origin of this question comes from watching [this YouTube video at 8:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cfctnaHyFM).

The equation to evaluate is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{i(j-k)}e^{i(j-k)x}|_{-\pi}^{\pi}$$

However, this equation can be evaluated normally as long as $j\neq k$.
For case where $j=k$,  the video says to use L'Hospital's Rule and it will evaluate to $x$ for $j=k$.

I tried just that but came out to be $-1/x$.

Here's my attempt:
The L'Hospital's Rule says $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$.

Here I use j instead of x:

$$f(j)=e^{i(j-k)x}=e^{ijx-ikx}$$ and $$g(j)=i(j-k)$$

and therefore $$f'(j)=\frac{1}{ix}e^{i(j-k)x}$$

and $$g'(j)=i$$

$$\lim_{j\to k}\frac{f'(j)}{g'(j)}=\frac{\frac{1}{ix}e^{i(j-k)x}}{i}=\frac{1}{ix}/i=\frac{1}{-x}$$

Where did I do wrong?

EDIT: I mistook derivate with integral for $f'(j)$

Comment: Your $f'(j)$ is wrong.

Comment: You wrote that $f'(j)=\frac{1}{ix}e^{i(j-k)x}$, but I get that $f'(j)=ixe^{i(j-k)x}$ instead. How did you get your result? Also, more fundamentally, note that at $j=k$, the numerator of $e^{i(j-k)x}$ becomes $e^{0}=1$ while the denominator of $i(j-k)$ becomes $0$. However, [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) requires that *both* the numerator and denominator go to $0$ or $\pm \infty$ so, at least on the surface, we can't use l'Hôpital's rule here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't agree with him in that you should evaluate the answer to the integral for $j = k$ using some trick. It's way easier to simply evaluate $\langle{\psi_j, \psi_j \rangle}$ directly. We can just plug this into the integral expression and get $$
\langle \psi_j, \psi_j \rangle = \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{ijx}e^{-ijx} dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi 1 dx = 2\pi
$$

Comment: Getting the integral to equal $\frac{1}{i(j-k)}e^{i(j-k)}$ only works when $j \neq k$. It is simply not equal to that expression when $j = k$ (Note that in that case you have $1/0$ which does not exist). You have to carry out the integration separately for $j \neq k$ and for $j = k$.